# HttpClientFactory without IServiceCollection (.net framework 4.6.2)

Tags: .net

I am curious on what is the best way to use `HttpClientFactory` without relying on Dependency Injection from `IserviceCollection`. Ever example assumes you are using DI, but I am working on a .Net 4.6.2 app and our code base is not set up to use it.

Is calling `HttpClientFactory.Create()` a valid way to get a HttpClient for each request? Should I be disposing it? Or am I better off just using a static instance of `HttpClient` and ensure that connection gets closed every min (using `ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout` and `ServicePointManager.ConnectionLeaseTimeout`)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using `HttpClientFactory.Create()` in my code and it seems ok so far...